# minikube install package using toolbox but the container does not internet conexion

Tags: kubernetes, internet-connection, toolbox, minikube

I'm wondering how can install a package inside the minikube VM. I need some tools.
I have tried the /bin/toolbox container, but It does not have internet conexion.

```
[root@docker-fedora-24 ~]# dnf update --verbose
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
DNF version: 1.1.9
Cannot download 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f24&arch=x86_64': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f24&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org].
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'
```

I have tried the same toolbox script in my computer and it is properly working.

What configuration parameters I'm missing in minikube or systemd-nspaw?
Or how can I cook a customized minikube VM?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What kind of packages would you like to install??

Comment: I would like to install my code by using make,  but make does not exists in minikube neither in toolbox container.

Answer (score 2):

You can run minicube without VM on your local docker (if you use linux):

`minikube start --vm-driver=none`

A alternative, run **toolbox** with `docker run --net=host ...` to make network for container more *transparent*. Troubleshoot your internet connection with `nslookup`, `traceroute`/`tracepath`, `curl -v`, `ifconfig`.
[http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch04*:_Simple_Network_Troubleshooting#.WfY1xGi0OUk](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch04_:_Simple_Network_Troubleshooting#.WfY1xGi0OUk)

Answer (score 2):

Minikube is not meant to be tweaked. The advised method is to prepare a [helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm) chart for your application. As part of the helm chart you can add whatever tool you need in your docker file... Including make... Then you can install or upgrade your package in kubernetes/minikube using helm.

Comment: I wanted to modify the minikube, not create a container with that software. Tahnks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to use `tcpdump` in the minikube VM.
I ended up using `minikube mount SRC-dir:DST-dir` to mount the host folder inside the VM and copying the tcpdump binary along with dependent libs (libcrypto and libpcap) to the mount point.
Then I executed tcpdump from the minikube VM and it worked.

Note: My host arch and the minikube VM arch (x86_64) was the same.
Note also: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:DST-dir has to be done.